# Setting up Amazon S3 for custom URLs

Tags: amazon-s3

I just recently started to use the S3 service from Amazon Web Services. I have no problem settings up buckets so that I can store files in them and link to them from my website, but the thing I am trying to do is make it so it looks like I am hosting the files off of my own website.

What I have done is created 3 buckets:

- css.mydomain.com
- images.mydomain.com
- js.mydomain.com

I then went over to my web hosting account and logged into cpanel. I clicked on Advanced DNS Zone Editor and put in the following information: http://gyazo.com/71fe0d3996df69021bd7f097436cca63

It has been over 4 hours now and stil when I go to for example http://css.mydomain.com/, I get a message indicating that the browser couldn't find the page.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have all user read permission on the files then I suggest you to do following things one by one...
- Only for confirmation - did you enable s3 website  ?
1. Check s3 file- are you able to access direct link -  http://css.mydomain.com.s3.amazonaws.com/defaulultpage.html
2. Check s3 website- are you able to access direct link -  http://css.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Let us know the result...

Comment: I was doing it completely wrong. I found a awesome tutorial and now I am all up and running :)